# How to avoid saving nil/blank in accepts_nested_attributes_for when displaying set number of fields for has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models, accepts-nested-attributes

My question is an edgecase of [how to avoid saving empty records on a nested rails form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865659/5783745). I have a simple `has_many`, where a user can have a maximum of 5 job titles.

```
# user.rb
has_many :job_titles
validates_length_of :job_titles, maximum: 5
accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_titles, 
  allow_destroy: true,
  :reject_if => proc { |att| att[:name].blank? }

# job_titles.rb
belongs_to :user
validates_associated :user
```

The proc should remove any blanks, but they get created anyway (!) since I have this in the users_controller, which is used to ensure there are always 5 form fields presented in the view:

```
# users_controller.rb
num_job_titles = @user.job_titles.count 
(5-num_job_titles).times { @user.job_titles.build }
```

With this, the blanks keep appearing in the database even before the form is submitted, since the previous code `build`s those blank records, and the model validation seems to allow it for some reason - I didn't expect it to.

#### Question

How can I ensure 5 fields are displayed for 5 different associated records (job titles), *and* ensure blank job titles aren't saved as records to the database?

Comment: You could use this gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon. It will allow you to dynamically create the relationships. With the condition of 5 max, I'm sure there's a way to limit the number of times a user can add more, but if you're using Rails views I would definitely check this out

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery thanks, I don't use cocoon yet, but I'll definitely have to investigate

Comment: Ya, I'm not 100% if it will fit your needs but it's pretty useful in dealing with dynamic relationships